# Is it ok that with fp:fast 3000.f/1000.f != 3.f?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, floating-point, visual-studio-2019, precision

I'm using MSVC 2019 v16.11.12.

When I tried compiling my code with **/fp:fast** instead of **/fp:precise**, my tests started failing.

The simplest case is:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_division) {
    float v = 3000.f;
    BOOST_TEST((v / 1000.f) == 3.f);
}
```

Failing with result:

> error: in "test_division": check (v / 1000.f) == 3.f has failed [3.00000024 != 3]

I understand that **/fp:fast** can have worse floating-point precision in some cases; but, here, it seems excessive...

How come it can't accurately divide 3000 by 1000?

I understand that 0.1 + 0.2 is not 0.3, but here all the numbers are representable and the division returns exactly 3 with **fp:precise**.

Is it possible that I have some other flag flipped which decreased the floating-point precision even more?

Comment: Well you cannot represent 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 accurately as float. While here a the numbers can be. And with fp:precise the final result matched expectations.

Comment: Folks, this is not the typical fp precision question. These integers are exactly representable in fp. Both gcc and clang optimize such as assert out as always being true. Given these are constant values, this would seem like an MSVC bug or at least pointlessly imprecise.

Comment: With /fp:fast the optimizer probably converts the `/ 1000.f` into `* .001f` -- mulitply by reciprocal, as multiply is faster than divide.  But .001 can't be exactly represented in FP, so you get rounding effects.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Which it is entitled to do under `fp:fast`. You should post an answer.

Comment: @GManNickG The phrase, "pointlessly imprecise" is wonderful when applied to integers represented as floating-point types. :-)

Comment: I tried to reproduce in godbolt without boost test but was unsuccessful. msvc used SIMD to do the calculation.

Comment: @drescherjm Can't reproduce on Compiler Explorer but [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/MP7bYvva4) gives a different bit pattern for the last result (`0x40400001` versus `0x40400000`) when I build with `fp:fast` on my local VS-2019.

Comment: @drescherjm Weird! All calculations are done at compile-time and the results placed in `COMDAT`. I see this in the generated asm: `__real@40400001 DD 040400001r ; 3` and then `__real@40400000 DD 040400000r ; 3`.

Comment: @AdrianMole I can reproduce it https://godbolt.org/z/bY1oeos7q

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the optimizations which is enabled by gcc's -ffast-math option (and probably msvc's /fp:fast option) is converting a "divide by constant" into a "multiply by reciprocal", as floating point divides are quite slow -- on some machines more than 10x as expensive as a multiply, as multipliers are commonly pipelined while dividers are less commonly pipelined.

With this, the `/ 1000.f` would get turned into a `* .001` of some precision, and .001 cannot be exactly represented in floating point, so some imprecision will occur.

More precisely, the closest 32-bit FP value to .001 is 0x1.0624dep-10, while the closest 64-bit FP is 0x1.0624dd2f1a9fcp-10.  If that 32-bit value is multiplied by 3000 you'll get 0x1.80000132p+1 or about 3.0000001425.  If you round that to 32 bits, you'll get 0x1.800002p+1 or about 3.0000002384.  Interestingly, if you use the 64-bit value and multiply by 3000, you'll get 0x1.800000000000024p+1, which when rounded to 64 bits is the exact 0x1.8p+1 value.

Comment: Yes. Changing the `v / 1000.f` to `v * 0.001f` causes the test to fail (on my local VS-2019), even when using `fp:precise`.

Comment: indeed MSVC generates mulss/fmul instead of divss/fdiv: https://godbolt.org/z/bY1oeos7q